# Read specifc rows and lines from multiple csv and export to one csv file

Tags: php, vba, csv

I receive weekly four csv files from four external sources. The csv files have the same design but contain different data. I would like to have specific rows and lines from all four files collected into one csv file.

Below is an example of how all four csv files is designed. I want to read Date, Name and Row5 and Row6 from all four csv files and then all this should be added into one csv file and set up as the 2nd example.

How could this be done? Within MS Excel as a script or maybe serverside using PHP?
I have been looking into a solution PHP. But i am not sure if it's even possible using PHP?

The delimiters used in the content (row1,row2,row3 etc.) is a comma (,). The top with date and name only uses a colon (:)

```
Date: 24-01-2014                            
Name: source1                           



Row1    Row2    Row3    Row4    Row5    Row6    Row7    Row8    Row9
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
ad4213  ad4214  ad4215  ad4216  ad4217  ad4218  ad4219  ad4220  ad4221
```

**2nd example**

```
Row5    Row6    Date    Name
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source1
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4218  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4219  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4220  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4221  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4222  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4223  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4224  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4225  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4226  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4227  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4228  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4229  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4230  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4231  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4232  ad4218  24-01-2014  source2
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source3
ad4218  ad4219  24-01-2014  source3
ad4219  ad4220  24-01-2014  source3
ad4220  ad4221  24-01-2014  source3
ad4221  ad4222  24-01-2014  source3
ad4222  ad4223  24-01-2014  source3
ad4223  ad4224  24-01-2014  source3
ad4224  ad4225  24-01-2014  source3
ad4225  ad4226  24-01-2014  source3
ad4226  ad4227  24-01-2014  source3
ad4227  ad4228  24-01-2014  source3
ad4228  ad4229  24-01-2014  source3
ad4229  ad4230  24-01-2014  source3
ad4230  ad4231  24-01-2014  source3
ad4231  ad4232  24-01-2014  source3
ad4232  ad4233  24-01-2014  source3
ad4217  ad4218  24-01-2014  source4
ad4218  ad4219  24-01-2014  source4
ad4219  ad4220  24-01-2014  source4
ad4220  ad4221  24-01-2014  source4
ad4221  ad4222  24-01-2014  source4
ad4222  ad4223  24-01-2014  source4
ad4223  ad4224  24-01-2014  source4
ad4224  ad4225  24-01-2014  source4
ad4225  ad4226  24-01-2014  source4
ad4226  ad4227  24-01-2014  source4
ad4227  ad4228  24-01-2014  source4
ad4228  ad4229  24-01-2014  source4
ad4229  ad4230  24-01-2014  source4
ad4230  ad4231  24-01-2014  source4
ad4231  ad4232  24-01-2014  source4
ad4232  ad4233  24-01-2014  source4
```

I hope someone here at Stackoverflow have an idea of how this could be done.

BR
Kristian

Comment: Is the delimiter in the csv file a comma or a tab?  In your example it looks like a tab, but you could have just copied and pasted from Excel.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details regarding the csv file. The delimiters is being used in the file:

`code`
Date: 24-01-2014
Name: test.csv



Row1,Row2,Row3,Row4,Row5,Row6,Row7,Row8,Row9
ad4213,ad4214,ad4215,4216,ad4217,d4218,a219,ad4220,ad4221
`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$foo = array( "source1.csv", "source2.csv","source3.csv","source4.csv");  
    $cont=0;
    foreach ($foo as $value) {
        $fh = fopen($value, 'r');
        if(!$fh) die('File no good!');

        $i=0;$j=0;
        while (!feof($fh )){
            $campo = fgetcsv($fh,4096,";");

            if($i < 2)
                $dataandsource[$cont][$i]=$campo[1];
            elseif($campo[5] != '' && $campo[6]!= ''){
                $rowfive[$cont][$j]=$campo[4];
                $rowsix[$cont][$j]=$campo[5];
                $j++;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        unset($rowfive[$cont][0]); //first row is 'row5'
        unset($rowsix[$cont][0]);  //first row is 'row6'
    $cont++;
    }
    for($x=0;$x< count($foo);$x++)
    {
        for($y=0;$y <= count($rowfive[$x]);$y++)
        {
            if($x==0 && $y ==0)
                echo "row5  row6  Date    Source<br>";
            else{
                if($rowfive[$x][$y] != '' )
                echo $rowfive[$x][$y].";".$rowsix[$x][$y].";".$dataandsource[$x][0].";".$dataandsource[$x][1]."<br>";
            }

        }
    }
```

i made this code with 4 csv file, with this information:

```
Date;24/01/2014;;;;;;;
Name;source1;;;;;;;



Row1;   Row2;   Row3;Row4;  Row5;Row6;Row7;Row8;Row9
ad4213;ad4214;ad4215;ad4216;ad4215;ad4218;ad4219;ad4220;ad4221
ad4213;ad4214;ad4215;ad4216;ad4217;ad4218;ad4219;ad4220;ad4221
ad4213;ad4214;ad4215;ad4216;ad4217;ad4218;ad4219;ad4220;ad4221
ad4213;ad4214;ad4215;ad4216;ad4217;ad4218;ad4219;ad4220;ad4221
ad4213;ad4214;ad4215;ad4216;ad4217;ad4218;ad4219;ad4220;ad4221
ad4213;ad4214;ad4215;ad4216;ad4217;ad4218;ad4219;ad4220;ad4221
ad4213;ad4214;ad4215;ad4216;ad4217;ad4218;ad4219;ad4220;ad4221
ad4213;ad4214;ad4215;ad4216;ad4217;ad4218;ad4219;ad4220;ad4221
ad4213;ad4214;ad4215;ad4216;ad4215;ad4218;test6;ad4220;ad4221
```

and the result is something like you want:

```
row5 row6 Date Source
ad4215;ad4218;24/01/2014;source1
ad4217;ad4218;24/01/2014;source1
ad4217;ad4218;24/01/2014;source1
ad4217;ad4218;24/01/2014;source1
ad4217;ad4218;24/01/2014;source1
ad4217;ad4218;24/01/2014;source1
ad4217;ad4218;24/01/2014;source1
ad4217;ad4218;24/01/2014;source1
ad4215;ad4218;24/01/2014;source1
ad4213;ad4221;24/01/2014;source2
ad4213;ad4221;24/01/2014;source2
ad4213;ad4221;24/01/2014;source2
ad4213;ad4221;24/01/2014;source2
ad4213;ad4221;24/01/2014;source2
ad4213;ad4221;24/01/2014;source2
ad4213;ad4221;24/01/2014;source2
ad4213;ad4221;24/01/2014;source2
ad4213;ad4221;24/01/2014;source2
ad5555;test6i;24/01/2014;source3
ad5555;test6i;24/01/2014;source3
etc...
```

Comment: It's almost fantastic. I think the reason for this is that the first five lines are text or just space The headers (row1,row2 etc.) is starting at line six. Sorry for the lack of details regarding the csv file. The delimiters is being used in the file:

The file top
"
Date: 24-01-2014
Name: test.csv
"

The content
"
Row1,Row2,Row3,Row4,Row5,Row6,Row7,Row8,Row9
ad4213,ad4214,ad4215,4216,ad4217,d4218,a219,ad4220,ad4221
"

Comment: After some small tweaks i made it work so it could read both delimiters. Many thanks for your work! 

BR
Kristian